# Use GoogleCharts change colors BarChart ruby

Tags: ruby, google-visualization

I'm trying to use GoogleChart to generate Pie and Bar charts from the same options (With custom if needed)
Everything works fine on the Pie, but the Bar charts don't want to take the colors. So I did research and I'm trying to add some *series* to force it to change the colors. But, so far, still blue!

Do you have any idea?

```
option = {
          width: 700,
          height: 200,
          colors: @colors,#basic array of colors
          # Don't display negative values
          min_value: 0,
          title: vote.question,
          backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
          is3D: true,
          # Displays items even if the value is 0
          sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
          legend: {alignment: "center"},
          vAxis: {format:'#%'},
          series: [{colors: '#3366cc'}, {colors: '#dc3912'}, {colors: '#ff9900'}, {colors: '#dc3912'}],
          isStacked: true
      }
```

I tried to add some series 'in hard' but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BarCharts color data by series, and it sounds like you have a single data series with multiple points.  If you want to change the bars' colors, you need to add a "style" role column to your DataTable, and specify the colors in that:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
data.addRows([
    ['Foo', 5, 'color: #3366cc'],
    ['Bar', 4, 'color: #dc3912'],
    ['Baz', 7, 'color: #ff9900'],
    ['Cad', 3, 'color: #dc3912']
]);
```

Comment: Thanks!
I had to deal with the ruby code and it takes times but I finally got it!

Answer (score 0):

My solution, using @asgallant tips. In Ruby.
@colors are basically an array of predefined colors.

```
  @colors = ['#3366cc','#dc3912',"#ff9900","#109618","#990099","#0099c6","#dd4477","#66aa00","#b82e2e","#316395","#994499","#22aa99","#aaaa11","#6633cc","#e67300","#8b0707","#651067","#329262","#5574a6","#3b3eac","#b77322","#16d620","#b91383","#f4359e","#9c5935","#a9c413","#2a778d","#668d1c","#bea413","#0c5922","#743411"]

  # Initialize the datatable that will contains our charts data.
  data_table = GoogleVisualr::DataTable.new
  data_titles = []
  data_votes = []

  # Headers
  data_table.new_column('string', t('choices'))
  data_table.new_column('number', t('shared.new_top_bar.votes'))
  data_table.new_column('string', 'color', nil, 'style');
  vote.vote_options.each do |vote_option|
    data_titles.push(escape_javascript(vote_option.title))
    data_votes.push(vote_option.votes)
  end

  data_titles.each_with_index do |elm, i|
    data_table.add_row([data_titles[i], data_votes[i], "color: "+@colors[i]])
  end

  # Configure the default options for the charts.
  option = {
      width: 700,
      height: 200,
      #colors: @colors,
      # Don't display negative values
      min_value: 0,
      title: vote.question,
      backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
      is3D: true,
      # Displays items even if the value is 0
      sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
      legend: {alignment: 'center'}
  }

  if data_titles.size > 5
    # Customisation if too much data.
    option[:height] = data_titles.size * 50# Make it bigger if there is too much parts to draw.
  end

  @charts[vote] = GoogleVisualr::Interactive::PieChart.new(data_table, option)
  @charts2[vote] = GoogleVisualr::Interactive::BarChart.new(data_table, option)
```